# Slow publish for clickonce applications

Tags: tfs, clickonce, publish

I have a publish build for several projects in a solution that are deployed using clickonce.  I've created a separate publish build in TFS, which basically compiles and deploys these projects.

The TFS build agent is running on the same Hyper-V VM as the TFS Server.  The build parameters are as follows:

```
/target:publish /p:GenerateProjectSpecificOutputFolder=true /property:PublishDir=\\networkshare;PublishingURL=https://www.publish.com /v:m
```

Output location is set to `PerProject`

The build itself is quite slow, but the longest time is taken in `Copy binaries to drop`.  The drop location is actually located on the same machine as the VM, but it takes over two hours.

EDIT: the last build for this has taken days.  The final stage - copy binaries to drop seems to be the issue.

EDIT: Changing "Staging location" from Copy build output to.." to "Copy build output to server has reduced the time significantly, but it still takes two hours, whereas the build itself takes around 5 minutes on my Dev Machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get this speeded up by disabling Hyper-V message queues.  Turning this off sped up the build from 2 - 3 hours to about 10 minutes!